# Order by a date inside of a foreach razor

Tags: javascript, c#, html, linq, razor

I have this partial that lists comments out but that looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, some of these dates are out of order...

is there a way to order by date inside this razor for each?

```
            <tbody>
            @foreach (var row in Model.*******.******.Where(d => d.Internal_Note == false))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @row.Note
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @row.NoteDT
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

Can I just do something like...

```
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var row in Model.GovernmentGroupApplication.tbl_AppStatusGvtGroup_Note.Where(d => d.Internal_Note == false).OrderBy(d=>model.Date) <--- pseudocode.
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @row.Note
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @row.NoteDT
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Have you tried the second option?

Comment: I had... but it was causing errors--its seeming to act more nicely to it--I think there was a caching issue before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct with `OrderBy()`, it's just your reference to the date field where you're wrong.

```
@foreach (var row in Model.GovernmentGroupApplication.tbl_AppStatusGvtGroup_Note.Where(d => d.Internal_Note == false).OrderBy(d=>d.Date))
```

Comment: Thanks-- I guess I had it right all along, there was a caching error going on before.  I am embarrassed to have asked this question--but since you did help me I will leave it open and choose this as the accepted answer.